# How to Glob all files in a directory match

Tags: bash, unix, gzip, glob

I have a uniform directory structure several layers deep.
Lets say CLIENT/USER/YEAR/TYPE/files

ex: client1/user1/2012/personal_files/file1.txt

what I want to do is compress all files from 2011.

essentially gzip */*/2011/*/*

This seems like it should be easy to do, but I can't seem to figure out how.  I could always write nested for loops, but isn't there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `for F in */*/2011/*/* ; do gzip "$F" ; done`

Comment: gzip: */*/2011/*/*: No such file or directory

Comment: @Smartelf, you also need to `shopt -s nullglob` -- that way, if no files are matched, bash will not print the wildcard expression verbatim

Comment: Do your file names contain spaces?  I just updated the code above to account for that (by adding quotes).